# how to handle repeated records in django

Tags: django, django-admin, repeat

I'm building poker website and I would like to create "Tournament schedule", something like [this](https://www.betsafe.com/en/pokerred/tournaments/schedule). Problem is, some tournaments are repeated every Monday, some always on 1st day of new month, some every two hours from monday to friday.
My two questions are:

1. How do I implement this, if all information is the same, but date changes by two hours for example. Duplication of records sounds like a stupid idea.
2. I am adding new tournaments in django admin. Since usually many fields stay the same for different tournaments, is there a way I could let user to save current form and load it later? That would make adding new tournaments much easier and quicker. (I need to store many different pre-populated forms and then choose, which one to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are having a poker tournament, you would want a historical record of each tournament, so you would need an unique record for each tournament that happens.  Otherwise, you would be mixing old tournaments with new, joining and unjoining player records from them all the time, etc...
2. Yes, you can set `default` as a `kwarg` in the Django models.py for each field, or use an `init` argument for User form data to pre-populate tournament forms for new tournaments based off the prior form they filled out.

Comment: 1. I will just aggregate tournaments, I don't need to store old ones. 2. I want to store those pre-populated forms and load them any time. So I need many different pre-populated forms.

Comment: So for Q1: Just save the time, and day of week, etc.. but not date specific then, I would think would be a good solution.  For Q2: Save data sets for the Forms specific to the User, or whatever you need. Should work fine.  Just try to implement DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as much as possible :)